# Debian - USB devices do not work if plugged into hub first

Tags: usb

If I plug the USB hub in first, and then the devices into the hub, everything works:

```
[ 4070.509322] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=214b, idProduct=7000, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 4070.509327] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 4070.509329] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[ 4070.509815] hub 1-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 4070.509976] hub 1-1.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 4070.795765] usb 1-1.2.1: new low-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[ 4070.912319] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=047d, idProduct=2048, bcdDevice= 6.00
[ 4070.912324] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4070.912327] usb 1-1.2.1: Product: Kensington Eagle Trackball
[ 4070.912329] usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: Primax
[ 4070.917756] input: Primax Kensington Eagle Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:047D:2048.0005/input/input23
```

However, if I connect the devices to the hub, and then plug the hub into the PC, the devices fail to work and dmesg shows the following log.

```
[ 4086.371524] usb 1-1.2.2: new low-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[ 4086.485546] usb 1-1.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2005, bcdDevice= 1.05
[ 4086.485552] usb 1-1.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4086.485555] usb 1-1.2.2: Product: DELL USB Keyboard
[ 4086.485557] usb 1-1.2.2: Manufacturer: DELL
[ 4086.489485] input: DELL DELL USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.2/1-1.2.2:1.0/0003:413C:2005.0006/input/input24
[ 4086.548027] hid-generic 0003:413C:2005.0006: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [DELL DELL USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2.2/input0
[ 4132.513591] usb 1-1.2: clear tt 1 (00a0) error -71
[ 4132.517826] usb 1-1.2: clear tt 1 (00b0) error -71
[ 4132.522125] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.526357] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.530737] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.534954] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.539311] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.539358] usb 1-1.2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4132.543587] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.547717] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.552167] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.556293] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.560674] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.565127] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.565128] usb 1-1.2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4132.569398] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.573611] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.577946] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.582189] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.586294] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.590691] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.590695] usb 1-1.2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4132.594796] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.599188] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.603333] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.607569] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.611917] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.616231] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.616233] usb 1-1.2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4132.620576] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.624873] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.629059] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.633282] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.637637] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.641954] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.641955] usb 1-1.2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4132.646119] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.650291] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.654541] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.658859] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.663125] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.667305] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.667307] usb 1-1.2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4132.671565] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.676005] usb 1-1.2-port1: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.680108] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.684427] hub 1-1.2:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[ 4132.688752] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.693020] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.697230] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.701537] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.701540] usb 1-1.2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4132.705819] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.710149] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.714299] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.718532] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.722672] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.726987] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 4132.727036] usb 1-1.2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 4132.728511] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 4132.728512] usb 1-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 4132.731296] usb 1-1.2-port2: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 4132.766536] usb 1-1.2.2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 4136.677660] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[ 4136.787042] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=214b, idProduct=7000, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 4136.787047] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 4136.787049] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[ 4136.787696] hub 1-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 4136.788037] hub 1-1.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
```

It appears to me that it detects the devices before the hub, and that seems to prevent them from working.

Does anyone know a solution to this or have any suggestions of things to try?

BTW the hub is an "iSOUL USB2.0 HUB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up buying another USB hub that works properly (a Trust HALYX with 3.2 gen1 ports)

Comment: I wouldn't bet this to be always the case, but even mine was due to hardware. Specifically, my network comprised, in order: an Asus T100TA tablet, an InLine microUSB extension cable, a TUSITA "charging OTG" hub and a GPS receiver with 4G capabilities. TLDR once I setup my SIM card (i.e. modem turns on and draws way more current) those errors [and others](http://askubuntu.com/q/341241) came up and no device could be detected anymore - unless I switch the hub/circuit to draw power from an external source rather than my PC. Then I found out that bypassing the extension cord also fixed everything.